# Are the notations $lg^2 n$ and $(lg n)^2$ the same thing?

Tags: calculus

I have a problem that is has the notation $lg^2 n$ and I just want to verify that it actually means / is the same as $(lg n)^2$

If it is not the same please tell me how to evaluate $lg^2 n$ (always assuming `lg` is base 2).

I do not have a source to quote from, I was just given a bunch of algorithms to sort out.  Sorting them isn't a problem for me as long as I know what they are saying :)  I retyped the notation exactly how it looks and provided it in the picture below.  I have included some other formulas too so you can compare the notations.  I imagine it was written as $lg^2 n$ just so he didn't have to use parenthesis, but I wanted to verify.

[image]

Comment: It is ambiguous. log^2 n might mean log log n. Can you quote from a source?

Comment: Who do we have to thank for the mathematical convention that $\cos^2 x$ and $\cos^{-1} x$ have to be read in different ways?

Comment: The fact that `lg lg n` is included *separate* from $\mathrm{lg}^2n$ suggests that $\mathrm{lg}^2n$ is indeed being used to mean $(\mathrm{lg} n)^2$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin I thought that too, but I wanted to be sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the source. Usually, the notation $f^n(x)$ to mean "$(f(x))^n$" is restricted to trigonometric and hyperbolic functions, and for other functions $f^n(x)$ means $$\underbrace{f\circ\dots\circ f}_{\mbox{$n$ times}}(x).$$

So you need to know what convention your source is using. It could mean either $\mathrm{lg}(\mathrm{lg}(n))$, following the usual conventions, or $(\mathrm{lg}(n))^2$, if the author is using the notation as in the case of trigonometric functions.

Comment: I asked around and in my particular case it means `(lg n)^2)`